# How to get value from javascript to php for database and js dropdown behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, database

**I Have created a 2 drop-down bar.
1)for selecting the floor.
2) depend on 1st drop-downbar[dynamically changed]**

### dropdown 1 code

```html
<select class="custom-select" id="selectFloor" name="selectFloor" onChange="changecat(this.value),getflatvalue();"> 
         <option disabled="true" selected>Select floor</option>
         <option value="floor_0"> Floor-0  </option>
         <option value="floor_1"> Floor-1  </option>
         <option  value="floor_2"> Floor-2  </option>
        </select>
```

**dropdown 2 code Using JAVASCRIPT**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var floorByCategory = {
    floor_0: ["Flat-1", "Flat-2", "Flat-3", "Flat-4"],
    floor_1: ["Flat-5", "Flat-6", "Flat-7", "Flat-8"],
    floor_2: ["Flat-9", "Flat-10", "Flat-11", "Flat-12"]
}

function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
         var catOptions = "";
         for (categoryId in floorByCategory[value]) {
           catOptions += "<option>" + floorByCategory[value][categoryId]
     + "</option>";
   }
   document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
**getflatvalue(); code for this function**

 function getflatvalue()//taking selected value of floor Option bar.
    {
     var flatval=document.getElementById("selectFloor").value;
     console.log(flatval);
    }
```

Que-1: Now how i will take the value of **selected value of Floor and Block** in **php**?
       I need the value of both variable to use in my db.

Que-2:Suppose i press submit button with some value and then were some error occur,then i come back to 
     this page dropdown-1 is 
      continued with previous selected value but dropdown-2 does not show value acccording to dropdown-1.

[image]

[image]
After submit-->error occure -->return to the same page.
That does not show the flat dropdown[dropdown-2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem lies with php variable that is used for firing the query for insertion process, check for SQL datatype & values you are inserting.

Comment: Thanks for a little but great idea :)

Answer (score 0):

**I set an Enum data type for some of my columns. by correcting that I can insert data through PHP.**

```js
var floorByCategory = {
    0: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    1: ["5", "6", "7", "8"],
    2: ["9", "10", "11", "12"]
}
```

```html
<select class="custom-select" id="selectFloor" name="selectFloor" onChange="changecat(this.value),getflatvalue();"> 
         <option disabled="true" selected>Select floor</option>
         <option value="0"> Floor-0  </option>
         <option value="1"> Floor-1  </option>
         <option  value="2"> Floor-2  </option>
        </select>
```

**I need to set floor and flat value like this.as per my "enum" data type.**
by correcting the values value can be insert.

Answer (score 0):

After correcting this question-2 is also solved...
Now the floor and flat both value are reset, and we need to select both manually.

[image]